# about if ... else ... getting stuck?

Tags: python, python-3.x

guys.
Recently,I ode a simple python program to do the job of synchronizing the Ubuntu repository, but I don't know why it is stuck at this conditional judgment, there is no standard output or error output, I tried to debug but still nothing, I see There is no problem here.
Please help.

```py
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# 2022-07-29

# 同步指定的ubuntu apt仓库到本地
# Synchronize the specified Ubuntu apt repository to the local

import subprocess
import os


rsync_server = 'rsync://rsync.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/'
# rsync_dest_major_dir = '/home/autox/mirror/'
rsync_dest_major_dir = '/opt/mirror/'

if not rsync_server.endswith('/'):
    rsync_server += '/'

if not rsync_dest_major_dir.endswith('/'):
    rsync_dest_major_dir += '/'

rsync_cmd = subprocess.Popen('which rsync', shell=True, text=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# print(rsync_cmd.read())

if len(rsync_cmd.stdout.read()) == 0:
    print('rsync command not found,please enture the command is available')
    exit(1)

sync_list = [
    'ubuntu/dists/focal/',
    'ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/',
    'ubuntu/dists/focal-proposed/',
    'ubuntu/dists/focal-security/',
    'ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/',
    'ubuntu/dists/bionic/',
    'ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/',
    'ubuntu/dists/bionic-proposed/',
    'ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/',
    'ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/',
    'ubuntu/dists/xenial/',
    'ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/',
    'ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/',
    'ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/',
    'ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/'
]

for i in sync_list:
    rsync_dest_full_dir = rsync_dest_major_dir + i
    if not os.path.exists(rsync_dest_full_dir):
        os.makedirs(rsync_dest_full_dir, mode=0o755)

    cmd = subprocess.Popen(f'rsync -avzPn {rsync_server}{i} {rsync_dest_full_dir}', shell=True, text=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # cmd_err = cmd.stderr.read().strip()
    # if cmd_err is not None:
    if cmd.stderr.read().strip() is not None:
        print(cmd.stderr.read().strip())
        print(f'"{i}" directory sync faild, stop syncing.')
        exit(2)
    else:
        print(cmd.stdout.read())
        print(f'"{i}" directory sync complete.')
```

Comment: probably its waiting for one of the `read`s

Comment: Its not because of rsync command,rsync -avzPn just dry run,not start to sync.

Comment: @L.Grozinger Read what? The site is working fine and I can access it normally

Comment: Please, extract a [mcve]. Also, if multiple things happen in a single line, split the line into separate statements to get further insight. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The documentation has a big warning regarding the use of `stderr.read()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr - and I'm honestly not sure why you are using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.run`